# Reading multiple Xml outputs of a stored procedure in ASP.Net applications

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, xmlreader

Assuming the following procedure (just for sample), how do I read the two XML outputs using XmlReader or DataReader in ASP.Net application?

```
create procedure doSomething
as

select EmpID, EmployeeName from tblEmployees for xml

select DeptID, DepartmentName from tblDepartments for xml
```

Performance is key, hence I don't want to load the XMLs into the memory by using a DataSet and then read the two XML outputs as two tables in the DataSet.

Comment: Why are you using here "for xml" ?

Comment: This is just an example. In place of the statements above, I have some complex code that returns data as XML. Middle tier process XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal DataSet to read the output from the SP.
Your 1st xml will come as ds.Tables[0] and 2nd as ds.Tables[1] and so on.

However, the complete xml will be splitted up in multiple rows across the table.
so you will have to loop around the available rows in the table and append the data to a string builder to get the complete XML data.

Eg:

```
StringBuilder strBldrXMLData= new StringBuilder();     
for (int i = 0; i < objDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            strBldrXMLData.Append(Utility.ConvertToString(objPermDS.Tables[1].Rows[i][0]));
```

Now your `strBldrXMLData.ToString()` will have the complete XML output of 1st select query. To interpret the XML against schema/objects, u can use `new System.Xml.XmlDocument().LoadXml(strBldrXMLData.ToString())`